# visually show counter from id in MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a database with 100 rows. I have a button that shuffle those id's and print out 3 random ids.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
   <button>Shuffle</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, description FROM fantasies_original ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 3";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

//print($res);
if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Store Number: " . $row["id"]. "<br>" .
             "Description: " . $row["description"]. "<br><br>";              
    }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

I would like to visualize the counter. So when I press the button I can see the number of the id there is loop through in the database. I have been looking everywhere to find a library that could do the job.

Does anybody knows a library or have a suggestion how to do that?

Comment: have a look at AJAX... why do you need a library for that if you cansimply write it yourself?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If that could do the job I will try to look into AJAX. Do you have a link, or an idea where I can look for that function in AJAX?